# Controls Re sizing Themselves in Designer on Build

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two controls inside a user control. They are set to be anchored left and right in order too size with the window as it changes size. For some reason I'm having tons of issues getting this to work properly.

Particularly, when ever I build the project and the control reloads itself, these controls triple in size, and extend way off the control. If I re size them and repeat the process it happens again!

Anyone have this issue or know what might cause it?

Comment: Do you have any code in the resize event of the usercontrol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to with @Bradley's comment and assume it could have been code in the re-size event. I was having other issues with control sizing and anchors, but I had removed all that code and rebuilt the assembly. Even so, I have had other times where I know the designer was somehow using old versions of the assembly (exceptions that had already been fixed). So that'a a possibility.

In any event I changed the anchors for these controls back to just left and top and the behavior stopped.